# Rails ajax Error: Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internet-explorer-8

Using `rails 4.0.0`, `ruby 2.0.0p247`, `jquery-rails 3.1.0`, and `jquery 1.10`.

Works in `FF`, `IE10+`, and `Chrome`.  Failing in `IE8` (have not tested `IE9`).

I'm trying to use ajax `data-remote` to cause clicking on a link to update a person's status.  But in `IE8` I'm getting a vague `JQHXR` Error: Invalid Argument. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Error occurs after line 157 jquery_ujs.js

```
154    // Only pass url to `ajax` options if not blank
155    if (url) { options.url = url; }
156
157    var jqxhr = rails.ajax(options);
158    element.trigger('ajax:send', jqxhr);
159    return jqxhr;
```

Debugging values in IE8 (after line 157, i.e. arrow on line 158)

```
[-]     options {...}   Object
        crossDomain null    Variant
        data    null    Variant
        dataType    "json"  String
        type    "patch" String
        url "/persons/status/1/stop"    String

[-]     jqxhr   {...}   Object
        readyState  0   Number
        responseJSON    undefined   Undefined
        status  0   Number
        statusText  "Error: Invalid argument."  String
```

My code:

```
<%= link_to status, status_path(person_id: p.id, status: status), remote: true, 'data-method'=> 'patch' %>
```

Why is my ajax call failing and what is invalid?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm wrong. you say it's *after* line 157... does that mean it's line 158?

Comment: I think you'd better show people some of your codes rather than showing only errors

Comment: I guess it is due to lack of support for PATCH method by IE 8. More details in this article - http://ilyai.github.io/rest/http/2013/06/11/http-method-support.html

Answer (score 0):

> I guess it is due to lack of support for PATCH method by IE 8. More details in this article - ilyai.github.io/rest/http/2013/06/11/http-method-support.html –  ilyai 13 hours ago

Had to use PUT instead of PATCH.